# Android LocationListener on Service with Thread

Tags: android, locationlistener

I´d like to implement a `LocationListener` in this way.

1 - Activity_first - Call `LocationListener`, but I have some spinner and this don´t respond when the `LocationListener` are `onStart()`. I´d like to implement with a `Thread`.

2 - When the `onLocationChanged()` in `LocationListener` gets called, I call `Geocoder`, and when the address is different than `null`, I save it on the shared preferences, and stop it.

Point 2, must be done in the background because the user might be in an `Activity` when I get the `Geocoder`'s address (about 10 seconds, it depend on connection)

I was testing with `IntentService`, but of course, I doesn't work.

My Code

```
public class Carga_1 extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.carga_1);

            // Todo Create Spinner, etc     
            startService(new Intent(Carga_1.this, LocationService2.class));

    }
}

public class LocationService2 extends Service { 
        public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";
        //public LocationManager locationManager; testted
        //public MyLocationListener listener; tested
        public Location previousBestLocation = null;
        Thread my_thread;


        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            Log.d("[GPS_coord]", "????");
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }


        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    MyLocationListener listener = new MyLocationListener();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
                }
            };
            my_thread = new Thread(r);
            my_thread.start();

        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            my_thread.stop();
        }

        private void get_address(double lat, double longi) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses;
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, longi, 1);
    //SAVE ON SharedPrefereces
                this.stopSelf();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("[GPS_geocoder]", "Decodificacion Erronea");
            }

        }

        public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
            public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
                Log.i("GPS_Service", "Location changed");
                Log.d("GPS_Service", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude() + " : " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude())));
                get_address(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Log.i("GPS_Service", "DES_habilitado");

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Log.i("GPS_Service", "Habilitado");

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }
        }
```